Editing Django default two factor auth login page
So, is it possible to edit of the default Django two factor authentication login page ? I copied the files from my virtual environment to my project directory but it still uses the the default Django template. I have the correct paths and everything. How can I solve this issue
I want to able to edit the Django two factor authentication login page to follow the rest of my web app, I want to get rid of the back and next buttons and have only a login button so when the user logs in, they can be taken to the token page(if they have 2 factor auth)

In your main template folder, add the following file: [templates]/two_factor/_base.html.
Also don't forget to set DIRS in your settings.py's TEMPLATES such as:
TEMPLATES = {
    "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
    ...
}

See also How to apply django-two-factor-auth in custom login page?
